# Android gcm message is overridden

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

iam trying the bellow code if a new message is sent it overrides the old message

here is the code

```
package com.androidhive.pushnotifications;

import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import static com.androidhive.pushnotifications.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, MainActivity.phone, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        int requestID1 = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        //PendingIntent intent =
          //      PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent intent =
                      PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID1, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

    }

}
```

after a bit of searching i came to know that notification id must be unique for each message

hence i tried this

```
int requestID1 = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

PendingIntent intent =
                          PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID1, notificationIntent, 0);
```

still the old message gets overridden what must i do so that the old message stays for atleast a day unless the user intents to remove the message from notification bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification id that needs to be unique is here:

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification); // change this 0 to requestID1
```